# How to make my app wait for incoming call in Android

Tags: android

I wanna know how to wait for the incoming call in my android app and do some task and again be in waiting state when the conversation is over?

Comment: Sure. What is your code so far? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Im getting started for this portion of my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a broadcastreceiver to catch CallState changes

in the manifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

create a Listener for the phone state:

```
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public static Boolean phoneRinging = false;

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

create the receiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    TelephonyManager telephony;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    // when finish your job, stop listen to changes
    public void onDestroy() {
        telephony.listen(null, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: yea, this solved my problem..but it seems that the respective method is called itself whenever there is a call, so how would i access my main activity from this method onCallStateChanged()?? or even from onReceive()???